# PrimeFaces p:media tag for using youtube

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, youtube, media

I have used PrimeFaces for playing a youtube video from url.But there is a problem in this tag.Some of the youtube links are playing but some of them are not playing.For example;

[this video](http://www.youtube.com/v/KZnUr8lcqjo) is playing but [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqOo7cYCBAo) is not playing.Here is the code;

```
< p : media value = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqOo7cYCBAo" width="600"
             height="400"  
             player="flash"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the link. The video link which it plays has some modifications. Its not exactly the same as the one you're trying to play.

https://www.youtube.com/v/KZnUr8lcqjo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mqOo7cYCBAo

Observe the strings after .com
You need to replace the string in proper format to make it play.